# Apex test class for the getting trending articles of Knowledge from Community

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, knowledge, articles

I need to get trending articles from the community. I created a apex class for that by using `ConnectApi.Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(communityId, maxResult)`.

I need to create a test class for that. I am using test class method provided by Salesforce for that. `setTestGetTrendingArticles(communityId, maxResults, result)` but I am getting this error

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: No matching test result found for Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(String communityId, Integer maxResults). Before calling this, call Knowledge.setTestGetTrendingArticles(String communityId, Integer maxResults, ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection result) to set the expected test result.

```apex
public without sharing class ConnectTopicCatalogController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> getAllTrendingArticles(){
        string commId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Customer Community v5'].Id;
        ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection mtCollection = ConnectApi.Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(commId, 12);
        System.debug('getAllTrendingTopics '+JSON.serializePretty(mtCollection.items));
        List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> topicList = new List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
        for(ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion mtopic : mtCollection.items)
        {
            String kmType = [SELECT KM_Type__c from Knowledge__kav WHERE id =: mtopic.id].KM_Type__c ;
            if(kmType != 'Class3 Error'){
                topicList.add(mtopic);
            }
        }
       return topicList;
    }
}
```

Apex test class for this

```apex
public class ConnectTopicCatalogControllerTest {
    public static final string communityId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Ansys Customer Community'].Id;
    @isTest
    static void getTrendingArticles(){
        ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection knowledgeResult = new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection();
        Knowledge__kav knowledgeData = [Select Id, knowledgeArticleId, Title, Summary, UrlName from Knowledge__kav Limit 1];
        List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> know = new List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
        know.add(new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion());
        know.add(new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion());
        knowledgeResult.items = know;
        // Set the test data
        ConnectApi.Knowledge.setTestGetTrendingArticles(null, 12, knowledgeResult);
        List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> res = ConnectTopicCatalogController.getAllTrendingArticles();
        // The method returns the test page, which we know has two items in it.
        Test.startTest();
        System.assertEquals(12, res.size());
        Test.stopTest();  
    }
}
```

Reference to create test class for ConnectApi https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

I am unfamiliar with Communities/Experience Cloud, I don't have an org available with Communities/Experience to test my hypothesis, and I haven't found a definitive statement in my interwebs searches. But I assume that Network is considered a "setup object" and thus its data is visible in a test context.

My assumption is bolstered by the fact that you do not seem to be getting a...

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

...error on this line...

```
string commId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Customer Community v5'].Id;
```

...during your test.

In a box on the page to which you link there is this statement:

> Use the test method signature that matches the regular method signature. If data wasn't registered **with the matching set of parameters** when you call the regular method, you receive an exception.

*[Emphasis added by me]*

Your `setTest` call:

```apex
ConnectApi.Knowledge.setTestGetTrendingArticles(null, 12, knowledgeResult);
```

Your `get` call:

```apex
ConnectApi.Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(commId, 12)
```

So if Network data is, indeed, test visible, you are setting your test data with a `null` Community Id value, and yet your code is still using the Id of the 'Customer Community v5' Community.